# BSDのIPv6 Routing Header Options Manipulation相当のことをLinuxで行いたい

Tags: linux, c, freebsd, ipv6

Linux で IPv6 Routing Header Options Manipulation と同等の機能を実現する方法はありますか？

`inet6_rthdr_space` などを利用したいです．

http://www.manpages.info/freebsd/inet6_rthdr_space.3.html

BSD で動いていたコードを gcc でコンパイルして Arch Linux で動かそうと思っています．

Comment: RFC2292 の実装については `cmsg(3)` に記載があります。また、これらの macro を使用した *BSD compatible な API の実装例が [newlib/libc/sys/linux/net/rthdr.c](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-newlib/+/94166e88ec63cfc4054794760cd2ab6483c86542/newlib/libc/sys/linux/net/rthdr.c) にあります。

Comment: @argus さん: `newlib/libc/sys/linux/net/rthdr.c` の存在は知らなかったです．`rthdr.c` をダウンロードして同時にコンパイルしたら無事 API が扱えました．ありがとうございます．追加で教えていただきたいのですが，この API を使って type 0 routing header (RH0) を持つパケットを作ろうと思っています．RFC5095 のため，*BSD では RH0 のコードが削除された と聞きますが，Linux では扱えますでしょうか？

Comment: 残念ながら、IETF の決定(deprecate source routing in IPv6)を受けて、BSD と同時期に Linux においても該当部分のコードが削除されてしまいましたので扱えませんね。。

Comment: ありがとうございました．表題の件は解決しましたので．RH0 については改めて別の質問に投稿しようと思います．

Answer (score 1):

RFC2292 の実装 [cmsg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html)  を使った *BSD 互換な API が [newlib/libc/sys/linux/net/rthdr.c](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-newlib/+/94166e88ec63cfc4054794760cd2ab6483c86542/newlib/libc/sys/linux/net/rthdr.c) にあるようです．

ありがとうございました．